# How do I add rel="nofollow" to links in blocks/menus/etc?

Tags: navigation

I want to add rel="nofollow" attributes to links that point to login/ToS pages in my Drupal 7 site. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the module you are looking for:

http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes

With Menu Attributes you can set the rel attribute (among many) on the admin section.

Comment: But doesn't this module affect only links in menu blocks? I'm interested in affecting all the links on a page.